# long to wide format with multiples

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like the following.

```
df = data.frame(val=c(4,2,6,3,4,5),
                algo=c("A","A","A","C","C","C"),
                id=c("james","james","james",
                     "james","james","james"))
df
```

I want to alter the structure of the data frame so that it's in wide format.

```
id     algo.A    algo.C
james   4         3 
james   2         4
james   6         5
```

I tried tidyr for this but get the following error.

```
> spread(df, id, algo)
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 5)
```

Any suggestions on how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a sequence column as there are duplicate identifiers. Specifically, `spread` cannot know that the different rows of `algo` are supposed to be different because they all have the same value for `id`. Specifying the `sep` argument in `spread` allows us to get the column name prefixes:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(id, algo) %>%        
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    spread(algo, val, sep = ".") %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
#   id    algo.A algo.C
#   <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 james      4      3
#2 james      2      4
#3 james      6      5
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(
    val = c(4, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5), 
    algo = c("A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C"),
    id = c("james", "james", "james", "james", "james", "james")
)
```

Comment: Thanks @CalumYou for the edits.  I rearranged the data.